# Keyboard stutter occurring after using citrix receiver - not resolved by reboot

Tags: windows, performance

I seem to have a rather frustrating keyboard stutter problem which occurs intermittently when using my windows 10 PC. Most recently I have noticed it seems to occur after I've left citrix running on my PC for a few hours. When I type, whether it be in a notepad file, running a command from the windows+run, typing a URL in a browser there are occasions where it seems as though half my typing goes missing. It will either ignore a whole host of characters (stutter & pause) and leave some or start printing additional characters so the words make no sense. It is not resolved by restarting my PC.  It will literally occur on the attempt to type my profile password at times.

I have run perfmon on various traces including the basics:

%Processor time Bytes Total/Sec (on all network adaptors) %Committed bytes in use %Idle Time (Physical disk)

I'd be quite surprised whether I'm suffering from a typical resource problem because my computer is fairly over spec for my requirements.

Processor: Intel Core i7-4770 3.4 GHz Installed RAM: 16 GB System Type: 64 bit x64 based processor. Windows runs off a SanDisk SDSSDXP480G SSD. Windows 10 Home edition

The above said I feel like logically speaking there must be a resource bottleneck somewhere causing the issue however I have yet to be able to find one that completely marries up with he problem. Only one counter thus far ever seems to max out and that is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller_2 which is currently maxing out and seems to have no impact whatsoever on my typing.

I have been reading various forums suggesting solutions like:

1) Uninstall/reinstall java. 2) Disable all your browser extensions. 3) Check performance related issues (pagefile). 4) Update windows & make sure you have all patches installed.

I have implemented all the above, the most recent being JAVA. Unfortunately given the intermittent nature of this issue I may not know the results for a while. Java has been the most recent change so we can see if this resolves. 2 & 3 & 4 did not appear to be the solution yet.

As I attempt solutions I will keep track of them here and hopefully I will find the solution.

Thanks

Phill

Comment: I thought i'd add an additional comment to this. Its been happening on and off for many months now. As soon as it appeared it mysteriously vanishes again after a few days. This most recent episode made my computer literally unusable and I've been forced to resort to my backup PC so I can actually get anything done. 

I have found another thread which suggested attempting to switch off filter keys but this is already disabled on mine so this is not the solution here: 

http://superuser.com/questions/425349/what-are-possible-causes-of-keyboard-lag-on-my-desktop-machine

Comment: I recently noticed that resource monitor seemed to show a very big jump in network traffic during the periods of business. Chrome being the major culprit however I can't really link the two directly and I'd be surprised if this has anything to do with Chrome. 

I have closed all Chrome windows and launched IE and I still have the same stutter issue.

Comment: Today I attempted a very simple test by waiting for the annoying stutter to occur and then closing literally every application except notepad and waiting for a while. I then attempted to type into notepad and the stutter still existed. Whatever is causing the stutter seems very unlikely to be a resource problem caused by applications running in the foreground.

Comment: Today I checked for Malware on my router. I'd heard that this might be an issue. However I checked as per this: 

http://www.howtogeek.com/227384/how-to-check-your-router-for-malware/

and it does not appear to be the case. I am still getting my IP assigned dynamically from my ISP.

Comment: I've also used spybot to scan my PC for spyware/malware with no luck there either.

Comment: I have attempted a keyboard driver reinstall. Wasn't possible because no drivers existed for this keyboard. It simply used the windows 10 standard.

Comment: Also added process explorer to see whether any processes are particularly busy to no avail as well.

Comment: Incredibly. The second post in this thread may have fixed it. I just plugged in wired keyboard into my PC and switched off the wireless logictec one and it seems totally responsive. 

http://superuser.com/questions/425349/what-are-possible-causes-of-keyboard-lag-on-my-desktop-machine?noredirect=1&lq=1

I will leave it a few days and if this resolves the problem I will close this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

So this turned out to be my keyboard. I had a wireless Logitech keyboard K750. Essentially there must have been some intermittent interference preventing the signal from reaching the bluetooth receiver.

I switched over to a cabled keyboard and I have not had the problem since. I guess it seems obvious to me now so definitely worth checking this first if anyone else suffers this problem.